# how to make post request baswith ic auth and content type x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: javascript, node.js

I should make a post request with basic `auth` and login and password in body (content-type: `application/x-www-form-urlencodeed`) 
I have tried several approaches but it does not work

I tried this, by specifying `content-type` in a header, but it does not work

```
const axios = require('axios')
let session_url = '10.50.141.75:8845/auth'

const requestBody = {
  login:    "node js",
  password: "react js"
}

const config = {
  headers: {
    'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencodeed'
  },
  auth: {
    username: 'testq',
    password: 'test'
  }
}

axios.post(session_url,requestBody, config).then(function(response) {
  console.log('Authenticated')
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.log(error)
})
```

I got an error 500, because of the request's body was not correct

Comment: Have you already solved your problem?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you should try:

```
axios.post(session_url, {
  data: requestBody,
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-type': 'application/json'
  },
  auth: {
     username: 'testq',
     password: 'test'
  }
}).then(function(response) {
  console.log('Authenticated')
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.log(error)
})
```